# How to set branch in Jenkins' Pipeline according to a parameter of the job?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

in Jenkins' section Pipeline, I want to set branch of the repository where Jenkinsfile resides to the value of a job's parameter (*BRANCH* here).[image: Part of the config of the job]

But the parameter, although set, is not replaced with its value. [image: Error from the run]

This should work, however: when I click on the questioning mark besides "Branches to build", the docs shows the possibility to supply the branch name as a variable. [image: Docs of the option]. Could you tell me what should I do better, please?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) What you are asking should not be hard with an actual pipeline script; what does yours look like?

Comment: @tripleee Oh, thank you for your notice about posting. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue reported similar to this.

Refer to the following JIRA for more info.
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42971

To get yours working you need to do the following:

1. Select the Prepare Environment to run
   [image: Prepare an Environment for run]
2. Select the Keep jenkins environment variables
3. Select the Keep Jenkins build variables
4. Then in your branch specifier your variable expansion will work. `${BRANCH}`